# Having Trouble opening up a Qt4 python file from another python(2.7) file

Tags: python, pyqt

I had two `.ui` files that I converted to python files with pyuic. What I am trying to do now is open one from the other.

Code for the main window:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'text.ui'
#
# Created: Thu May 30 11:40:12 2013
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.10
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from hi import Ui_Dialog

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 520, 98, 27))

        ##Connects the clicked event to the open function
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open)


        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 60, 541, 121))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 25))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton", None))

    def open(self):



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

code for the second window (dialog):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'hi.ui'
#
# Created: Thu May 30 11:41:17 2013
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.10
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 240, 341, 32))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("buttonBox"))
        self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(Dialog)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 10, 391, 161))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tabWidget"))
        self.tab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab"))
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.tab)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 40, 104, 78))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.tab_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab_2"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, _fromUtf8(""))

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("accepted()")), Dialog.accept)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("rejected()")), Dialog.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("Dialog", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Ubuntu\'; font-size:11pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">hi</p></body></html>", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("Dialog", "Tab 1", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("Dialog", "Tab 2", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My guess is that I'm going to have to import the other file and call some method to make it show. Is there a way to do it like this:

```
secondWindow = Ui_Dialog
secondWindow.show()
```

or something along those lines? I tried something like that but it says there is no method show(). Is that because of the way the class is constructed?

I even tried something like this:

```
def nom():
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My idea was that if the code under `if __name__=="main":` gets executed on startup why can't I just put that into another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An simple working example would be this:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
from dialog import Ui_Dialog

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.show_dialog)
    def show_dialog(self):
        dialog = Dialog()
        ret = dialog.exec_()
        if ret == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
            self.textEdit.append('accepted')
        else:
            self.textEdit.append('rejected')

class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It works if you name your first file `mainwindow.py` and the second file `dialog.py`.
The first class inherits from `Ui_MainWindow` and the other one from `Ui_Dialog` so they get the code out of the imported file. Then they call `setupUi(self)` which "generates" the window.

At the bottom in the `if __name__ ...` thing it instantiates the two classes and then `show()` will work and shows the window.

If you generate code with pyuic and then change the code it will be simply overwritten if you modify your `.ui`-file and regenerate the python code! Because of this you should always make a "main" file and import the GUI into it.

*the code will only work if you remove `from hi import Ui_Dialog` and `def open(self):` from your first file*

your own functions like the `open` (this should get another name because of the builtin `open`) should go into the main file!

**Edit:** Changed the code so that the dialog is showed when "PhusButton" gets clicked.
To "start" a dialog you need its `exec_` method. In the code above the `clicked` signal from the button is connected to the `show_dialog` method. This method gets called after every click on the button. Then it executes the dialog and writes into the textfield if the dialog was closed with *ok* or with *cancel*.

Comment: What I actually want to do is to be able to call the dialog qt-py file from the mainwindow. How would I go about doing that?

Thanks for this little snippet!

[I tried it this way:](http://pastie.org/7984613)

Comment: Ok, I've changed the code, so it will open the dialog on every click of the button.